# Attempting to create validation for a number, crashes when attempting to test

Tags: java, android

The Title is the best I could explain it. I am attempting to create a validation for a number box in Java, using android studio. However, the validation, when it should instead display the message "weight must be entered!", the program collapses upon itself. Any idea what could be wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
package com.example.student.project8a_medicalcalculator;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.EmptyStackException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
double weightEntered;
double convertedWeight;
final double conversionRate = 2.2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    final EditText weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Weight);
    final RadioButton lbToKilo = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.LbToKilo);
    final RadioButton kiloToLB = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.KiloToLb);
    final TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Results);
    Button convert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bnConvert);

    convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String weightV;
            weightV = weight.getText().toString();
            if (weightV.equals(" "))Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Weight must be entered! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            weightEntered = Double.parseDouble(weight.getText().toString());
            DecimalFormat tenth = new DecimalFormat("#.#");

            if (lbToKilo.isChecked()){
                if (weightEntered <= 500){
                    convertedWeight = weightEntered / conversionRate;
                    result.setText(tenth.format(convertedWeight) + " kilograms");
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Pounds must be less than 500", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
            if (kiloToLB.isChecked()){
                if (weightEntered <= 225){
                    convertedWeight = weightEntered * conversionRate;
                    result.setText(tenth.format(convertedWeight) + " pounds");}
                    else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Kilos must be less than 225 ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`Double.parseDouble()` will raise `NumberFormatException` exception and make app crash when when you try to parse an empty string.

you checked the input string, but run `Double.parseDouble()` even it equals empty.

You could do as below:

```
if (!weightV.isEmpty()){
    weightEntered = Double.parseDouble(weight.getText().toString());
    ......
}else{
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Weight must be entered! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say:  *the validation, when it should instead display the message "weight must be entered!", /the program collapses upon itself*  
So you put a space `" "` in the EditText and expect to see the Toast.  
You would see the Toast if you change the code:

```
if (weightV.trim().isEmpty()) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Weight must be entered! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return;
}
```

But without `return` the code continues to execute and `Double.parseDouble(weight.getText().toString())` throws an exception because an empty EditText's text is not a valid number.